# C# List box selected index resets to 0 after every timer refresh

Tags: c#, listbox, timer, indexing, selected

I've got a listbox that displays data pulled from a database on every timer tick, set at 2 seconds. The data needs to be as current as possible at all times. I'm using an event handler SelectedIndexChanged to display detailed data from a selected index of the listbox.

The problem I have currently is that the selected index resets to 0 after every refresh. I need a way to continue refreshing, but to retain the data in the text fields.

Comment: can you post in your code under the timer event

Comment: Are you refreshing items in the listbox, or replacing the entire contents of the listbox?

Comment: Replacing entire content within.

Comment: You're going to have an interesting problem if the item that you're editing is removed from the database and is no longer in the listbox.

Comment: That instance won't happen in our scenario. The application has 5 stations, and at no point is data deleted. The data is simply moved from station to station with changes we make to a table item "status." For example: Station B is changing the items from status 2 to status 3. Station C(me) is interested in all data of statuses 3,4,5. Once the data leaves Station B, only I can view it. The only one deleting items in the way you speak of would be myself. Also, it wouldn't be 'deleted', it would be set to a different status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the selected `ListItem` into a variable before you do the refresh and set the value back to it afterwards.

Comment: Where in the code would I do this? My timer calls a populate method, which pulls from the database and displays in the list box. By populating the list box, the index is automatically set to 0. If I put it after the populate, it would be set to 0 right away. If I put it in the event handler for selected index change, it will auto-update on every full refresh back to 0.

Comment: Save it before the populate method, set it after the populate method.

Answer (score 0):

That is a normal behavior and to override that you will need to write code to reselect the Item after adding new item. 
To reduce the Flicker you can try calling [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) on the ListBox and then after Adding Items Call `ResumeLayout()`